# How to select specific rows and columns in 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If I have an 2d array such as

```
A = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
```

How can I select `row = [0, 2]` and `column = [0, 2]` using parameters?
In MATLAB, I can simply do `A[row, column]` but in python this will select 2 elements corresponding to (0,0) and (2,2).

Is there anyway I can do this using some parameters as in MATLAB?
The output should be like
[0 2

8 10]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to select row = [1,3,5] and column=[1,3,5] from A

Comment: Yeah, but what does that look like? People who know Python but not MATLAB can help you if you provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a block of elements - as MATLAB does, the 1st index has to be column vector.  There are several ways of doing this:

```
In [19]: A = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [20]: row=[0,2];column=[0,2]

In [21]: A[np.ix_(row,column)]
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 8, 10]])
In [22]: np.ix_(row,column)
Out[22]: 
(array([[0],
        [2]]), array([[0, 2]]))

In [23]: A[[[0],[2]],[0,2]]
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

The other answer uses `meshgrid`.  We could probably list a half dozen variations.

Good documentation in this section:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing

Comment: Agreed there are numerous ways! Also `mgrid` would be another approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
A = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
print np.ravel(A[row,:][:,column])
```

to get:

```
array([ 0,  2,  8, 10])
```

Answer (score 1):

`MATLAB` creates a 2D mesh when indexed with vectors across dimensions. So, in MATLAB, you would have -

```
A =
     0     1     2     3
     4     5     6     7
     8     9    10    11
    12    13    14    15
>> row = [1, 3]; column = [1, 3];
>> A(row,column)
ans =
     0     2
     8    10
```

---

Now, in NumPy/Python, indexing with the vectors across dimensions selects the elements after making tuplets from each element in those vectors. To replicate the MATLAB behaviour, you need to create a mesh of such indices from the vectors. For the same, you can use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) -

```
In [18]: A
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [19]: row = [0, 2]; column = [0, 2];

In [20]: C,R = np.meshgrid(row,column)

In [21]: A[R,C]
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 8, 10]])
```